# How to find reason for MAUI app failure on Android ([libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV))?

Tags: android, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, maui

I am trying to explore .NET 6 with MAUI preview 14 to run code on Windows, Android and other platforms.

While my code works fine on Windows, on Android, where I run my code using VS 2022 17.2 Preview 2 in a Pixel 5 emulator with x86_64 architecture, any attempt to instantiate the central instance of the `Processor` class (with e.g. `var processor = new Processor(true);` of a library named SaxonCS (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonCS/) I use crashes the application with an error `[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)`

```
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.mauiapp4sax1121test2/files/.__override__/Singulink.Numerics.BigDecimal.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.mauiapp4sax1121test2/files/.__override__/Singulink.Numerics.BigIntegerExtensions.dll [External]
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10 in tid 14860 (pp4sax1121test2), pid 14860 (pp4sax1121test2)
```

What does that error mean, how to find out in more detail what causes it and how to avoid it?

As for the logs, they don't seem to show more info, at least to me as the error doesn't seem to be more detailed:

```
Uhrzeit    Gerätename    Typ    PID    Tag    Meldung
03-22 11:15:53.714    pixel_5_-_api_30    Error    14953    DEBUG    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
03-22 11:15:53.633    pixel_5_-_api_30    Error    14860    libc    Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10 in tid 14860 (pp4sax1121test2), pid 14860 (pp4sax1121test2)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the logcat output for your application?  And how did you execute x86 or x86_64 shared dlls on armv71 or aarch64 devices?

Comment: @PavelSamsonov, see whether the edit answers your questions, I am afraid the log, at least for me, didn't have more detailed information. I have put the used version of VS and Android emulator in the question text.

Comment: But why are libraries ".dll" and not ".so", is this possible?

Comment: I am running in VS 2022 debug mode and the first output is what the VS output console shows when the attempt to run the app crashes. I understand it is .NET 6 loading its dlls, I don't know which layer Microsoft uses to run .NET 6 on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed this issue as a potential bug on MAUI in https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6811.

@lambdageek from Microsoft was able to identify the bug https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/76312 in the Mono runtime that caused this crash, his fix is now in the November 2022 6.0 .NET service update and in .NET 7.0 GA so using these up to date versions of .NET and MAUI under Android SaxonCS does no longer crash.